# Is a queue needed to retrieve data from epoll event?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

I am trying to understand the usage of epoll in linux. After reading few answers here and some articles i have understood that an epoll_create returns a file descriptor for an epoll instance created.

And it can be used to look upon some events that are registered to be monitored.
My problem of understanding is as follows.

I have 2 processes A and B and they want to communicate with each other.

1. Should i create 2 separate file descriptors to attach events and to look upon ?
2. How can 'A' send a data to 'B' and where will the sent data reside? Is a queue needed from where the file descriptor lets A to retrieve data ?

This question might not be well formed but i am really confused about this . Please help clarifying this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `epoll` is not an IPC mechanism - it's an I/O multiplexing mechanism, it's different. If you just want communication between `A` and `B`, why don't you use a pipe or a FIFO (aka named pipe)? Have you heard about it? I'll be happy to post an answer if you'd like, though it's not really related to epoll.

Comment: @Filipe.. Thanks for your reply. I want to use epoll with sockets. If i use sockets the data received can be read by 'read' call ?? i read few articles that epoll events structure has a pointer for data. So i am confused how to use sockets with epol (particularly retrieving data when an event occurs)

Comment: Well, do you know how to use sockets in the first place? It looks like you're learning socket programming, and it may be a little too early to jump to `epoll` right away. You typically worry about using `epoll` when doing I/O multiplexing and/or your application needs to scale. You can do socket programming very easily with raw `read(2)` and `write(2)` syscalls. Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: @Filipe.. Thanks again for the reply.. I have not done any coding yet. I m just trying to understand usage of epoll and if it can be used with queues. Now i ve understood that epoll isjust a mechanism for pollin between sockets. What i am trying to achieve is i am planning to make a bridge or something between two modules where one sends data in sockets and other module should some how be able to receive it in message queues. So the bridge should somehow receive socket data and put it into message queue. ( i was wondering if this can be done directly with epoll)